# Select averages in each GROUP BY group?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, aggregate-functions

===== EDIT: Modified original question =====

Based on the comments, I have edited the original question (I left the original question at the end) as follows:

I have sample employee data stored in a table (emp) like this:

```
ID   | Key | Value
1000 |  1  | Engineer
1000 |  2  | Male
1000 |  3  | 30
1001 |  1  | Manager
1001 |  2  | Female
1001 |  3  | 35
```

where the keys are mapped in another table (key_prop):

```
Key | Value
1   | Type
2   | Sex
3   | Age
4   | ID
```

I'm looking for statistics of the employees grouped by Employee Type:

```
Type      | Count | Number of Males | Number of Females | Avg Age 
Engineers |       |                 |                   |
Managers  |       |                 |                   |
```

It's easy to get the 1st column (I am using Oracle SQL):

```
SELECT (key_prop.value, COUNT(key_prop.value))
FROM 
  emp 
INNER JOIN
  key_prop
ON
  key_prop.id = emp.id
AND
  key_prop.value = 1
GROUP BY key_prop.value
```

But I can't seem to get the other columns in the same query.  Do I have to group several inner joins together or use nested SQL queries?

== ORIGINAL POSTING BELOW ==

I have sample employee data stored as rows of KVPs like this:

```
Type | Engineer
Sex  | Male
Age  | 30
Type | Manager
Sex  | Female
Age  | 35
...
```

I'm looking for statistics of the employees grouped by Employee Type:

```
Type      | Count | Number of Males | Number of Females | Avg Age 
Engineers |       |                 |                   |
Managers  |       |                 |                   |
```

It's easy to get the first column (I am using Oracle SQL).  But I can't seem to get the other columns in the same query.

Comment: How are the rows connected to each other?  SQL tables are inherently unordered.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I may have oversimplified the example so that the problem is easier to understand.  There's actually another KVP to store the iD of each employee, and the first column is actually part of another table.

Comment: "oversimplify" is an insult towards people who know better(such as @Gordon Linoff). Please don't oversimplify.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear to us where the key values come from.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion; this is my first time posting.  I have edited the original question.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first aggregating by the employee id and then reaggregating:

```
select type,
       count(*) as num,
       sum(case when sex = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as males,
       sum(case when sex = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) as females,
       avg(cast(age as decimal(5, 2))) as avgage
from (select employeeid,
             max(case when col1 = 'type' then value end) as type,
             max(case when col1 = 'sex' then value end) as sex,
             max(case when col1 = 'age' then value end) as age
      form employees e
      group by employeeid
     ) t
group by type;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should group by type and then use aggreagate functions with accurate conditions:

```
SELECT 
    type,
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Sex = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS number_of_males,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Sex = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS number_of_females,
    AVG(age) AS avg_age
FROM employees
GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in MySQL working ...

Let's build the DB:

```
mysql> create database test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use test;
Database changed

mysql> create table e(name VARCHAR(10), type VARCHAR(10), sex VARCHAR(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into e set name='john', type='barvaz', sex='M';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into e set name='miko', type='barvaz', sex='M';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into e set name='mako', type='barvaz', sex='M';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into e set name='mona', type='barvaz', sex='F';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now just a sample:

```
mysql> select *,IF(sex='M', 1, 0) AS sex FROM e;
+-------+--------+------+-----+
| name  | type   | sex  | sex |
+-------+--------+------+-----+
| john  | barvaz | M    |   1 |
| miko  | barvaz | M    |   1 |
| mako  | barvaz | M    |   1 |
| mona  | barvaz | Y    |   0 |
+-------+--------+------+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Do the queries:

```
mysql> select *,SUM(IF(sex='M', 1, 0)) AS sex FROM e;
+-------+--------+------+------+
| name  | type   | sex  | sex  |
+-------+--------+------+------+
| john  | barvaz | M    |    3 |
+-------+--------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

And what we were searching for:

```
mysql> select type,sex,SUM(IF(sex='M', 1, 0)) as Males, SUM(IF(sex='F', 1, 0)) AS Females FROM e;
+--------+--------+-------+---------+
| type   | sex    | Males | Females |
+--------+--------+-------+---------+
| barvaz | M      |     3 |       1 |
+--------+--------+-------+---------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Of course you can add in some GROUP BY as you wish.

Comment: Are you aware that Oracle and MySQL have a different syntax? The above will not work for Oracle (or any other standard compliant DBMS). For one because Oracle (or SQL in general) does not have an `IF` statement, but more importantly because the `group by` you use is also invalid SQL and won't work in any other DBMS except in MySQL

Answer (score -2):

I am not an Orcale SQL specialist. But I do know MySQL and ASIC SQL quite good. Usually in this cases I use IF and SUM.

Hence:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(Sex='Male', 1, 0)) AS number_of_males,
  SUM(IF(Sex='Feamle', 1, 0)) AS number_of_females,
  AVG(age) AS avg_age
FROM
 Employees
WHERE
 type='Engineer';
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: That is neither valid standard SQL nor valid SQL for Oracle.

Comment: I have no idea why you wrote that or voted me down ... Since you haven't tried it yourself ... see my second answer below !

Comment: Did you see the `oracle` tag?  The SQL is simply not going to work with Oracle (because there is no `IF`)